# how can I get only the text part of an innerHTMLtext that has an image combine on it just like this:

Tags: javascript

```
<div id="demo">
   <img src="uparrow.png"> 
      &nbsp; MORE CONTESTS &nbsp; 
   <img src="uparrow.png">
</div>
```

I just need to get the MORE CONTESTS part, but because of the images I cannot get it to work. every time I'm running the page the browser do some funky thing with the parameters of the image, and therefore it doesn't match with the validation, any help with it?

Comment: you need to clarify your question. What exactly are you trying to do/expected output and what have you tried so far?

Comment: ok I'm trying to create a small library for translation, but some of the html tags have img on it. just like the one I post previously. that was just an example but is the same idea. however every time I tried to get the text with the image, the browser do some something very weird with the parameters of the image. therefore it doesn't change the text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.textContent` instead of `.innerHTML`. It returns just the text, not other HTML elements.

Comment: Oh then I'm sorry. Was curious where the code came from. I'll delete my comment then :)